# What is the electronic configuration of La⁺?

Tags: electronic-configuration, periodic-table

> Second IP of La is most likely to second IP of which element:
>
> (**1**) Be
>   (**2**) Ba
>   (**3**) Ca
>   (**4**) Zn

The given answer is calcium. I don't understand if the 6s electron or the 5d electron leaves on ionization. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

During ionization only the electrons in last shell leaves.So its 6s